# Purge all user related data in GitLab self managed instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

We have a self-managed gitlab instance running in our office servers. There was a server crash and the data driver were corrupted. After replacing the hardware, all GitLab data was restored from backup.

However for some reason my user account was not restored. I tried logging in, it said invalid password. I tried resetting password, said it will send reset email if account exists. But account doesn't exist so no email sent. I tried creating a new account with my previous email and user id, it said user id and email already exists.

I tried logged in through admin panel to delete the user. But my user was not in the list of users. I tried creating a new account from admin panel and showed user id and email already exists. There, are still commits with my user name. But clicking on that username doesn't take me anywhere.

I tried finding the user using the GitLab Rails console and tried the following queries:

```
> User.find_by_username('myuser')
> nil
```

```
> user=User.find_by(username: 'myuser')
> nil
> User.delete(user.id)
> nil
```

I also tried deleting the user using GitLab API following this [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html) but to no avail.

**How can I completely purge this user so that a new user can be created with my email and username?**